# QGIS - Create evenly distributed boundaries using multiple points as the source

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-grid

I've got series of coordinates that are the centroids and I am wondering if it's possible to create a grid polygon if their boundaries are less about distance and more about spacing evenly between the two.  I guess distance between neighbouring point divided by 2 would generate one line of the polygon.

I was playing around with Buffers but I don't believe that's what I am looking for since it's asking for a distance value.

My points all look like this when I open the layer in QGIS.

[image: points]

Using the Rectangles,ovals,diamonds(fixed) found in Processing Toolbox, I can get close but for some reason the edges aren't correct, seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Voronoi polygons` with the point layer as input. No need to reproject, works with projected or geographic CRS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear what you want to do, but if you want to create grid polygons from your points you can use "Rectangle ovals diamonds". Set width and height to match the point spacing:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I had found some other answer with this plugin, that looks correct for what I want.  Now to find the plugin, it doesn't show up in the available plugins.  Is it possible this plugin doesn't work on the latest QGIS?  I don't see it on their website plugin directory either.

Comment: I found it in the Processing Toolbox but it doesn't look quite like your screenshot (I don't have meters options to pick, just degrees and when I try my results look close but not quite, the edges are missing grids or expanded.  I'll edit the original post with a new screenshot

Comment: Sounds like you are using a coordinate system with degrees as units. [Reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) it to a coordinate system with units in meters, for example one of the [UTM zones in Canada](http://glaikit.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/canada-grid.jpg), if that is where you are

Comment: That could be, the source is from ERA5 climate data which has a little memo that `may require you to manually assign a spatial reference. In this case use a 6367.47km sphere for all data if possible.`. Reprojecting to UTM and rerunning the rectangles produced rotated results.  What I am looking to do might not be achievable